# Не корректно подключается файл CSS к HTML

Tags: html, css, color

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>html+css</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1 class="head1">Это самый главный заголовок</h1>
  <h2 class="head2">Это второй после самого главного заголовка</h2>
  <h3 class="head3">А это заголовок заголовочного заголовка</h3>
<p class="paraghraph"> Ублюдок мать твою а ну иди сюда говно собачье </p>
</body>
</html>



.head1 {
  color :green;
};

.head2 {
  color :blue;
};

.head3 {
  color :orange;
};

.paraghraph {
  color :blue;
};
```

Причем,если поменять значение в классе .head1 ,цвет поменяется ,с остальными классами так не работает.

P.S. если есть мысли подскажите почему если файл CSS лежит в одной папке с HTML файлом,то подключается всё корректно, если же файлы находятся в разных папках то подключение файла не происходит.

Comment: Работаю в редакторе Atom.

Comment: А каким образом Вы подключаете файл из другой папки? Естественно если файл находится в другой папке, то и путь к файлу тоже меняется.

Comment: Также `;` после фигурных скобок в CSS не нужны. Потому остальное и не работает.

Comment: Дело в том что путь указывал к другой папке ,в которой и лежал файл соответственно,в данном случае я уже оставил файл в той же папке где и HTML лежит.

Comment: Убрав   ; проблема решилась,благодарю за отклик!

Answer (score 4):

Не нужно ставить точку с запятой после блока стиля. В CSS они ставятся только после <s>строк</s> значений свойств.

Верный пример будет такой:

```css
.head1 {
  color: green;
 }

.head2 {
  color: blue;
}

.head3 {
  color: orange;
}

.paraghraph {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
      <title>html+css</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1 class="head1">Это самый главный заголовок</h1>
      <h2 class="head2">Это второй после самого главного заголовка</h2>
      <h3 class="head3">А это заголовок заголовочного заголовка</h3>
    <p class="paraghraph"> Ублюдок мать твою а ну иди сюда говно собачье </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Точнее не строк, а значений свойств.

Answer (score 0):

Подключить файл стилей из другой директории можно таким образом.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">
```